# manually creating photo tags in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, tagging

I want to manually(without using any gems or plugins) create tagging system for the photos in my rails application. Is there any tutorial or help ?
Please guide.

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

It's not too bad, according to [this blog post](http://kristiannissen.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/running-your-own-taggable-in-rails-isnt-that-hard/#comment-230).